# create multicursor in Atom

Tags: atom-editor, multiple-cursor

I use Atom on Ubuntu 17.10 with wayland window manager.

I can create multiple cursors with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+Mousclick or with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to select the next same string.

But how can I for example mark some lines and create a cursor at the start of each line?

Also would be great to use search and find-all to select lots of results in a text to create a cursor at all these results.

I used this workaround at the moment by selecting the line-break and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to select the next linebreaks too with extra cursors, then go one left and Pos1 to have the cursors at the start of each line.

I wanted to select a string that repeats about 200 times in a dataset of 3000 text-blocks in a bunch of output and then I wanted to expand the selection to each of those blocks. That would have been really easy with multiple cursors. I solved this another way now, but for the next time I would like to see a complete instruction manual about how to create multiple cursors in the standard atom setting. I couldn't find this. Search-engines give me lots of plugins and solutions in different multicursor plugins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the manual that explains it like in sublime ([ctrl alt up and down](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html)):

- Alt+Shift+Up and Down

see: https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/editing-and-deleting-text/#multiple-cursors-and-selections

What is missing in the manual is also a useful option:

1. use "find all" with the search tool in Atom (CTRL+F)
2. press Alt + Enter to create cursors at all the found locations.

see: https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-do-i-create-multiple-cursors-from-search-result/53231/5

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make it easy so I could just use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>⬇️</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>⬆️</kbd> to have multiple cursors. This was my solution and I think its the easiest:

```
# From Atom -> Keymap add the following lines:
'.editor':
  'alt-up': 'editor:add-selection-above'
  'alt-down': 'editor:add-selection-below'
```